# Creating a toolbar using Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have been trying to create a toolbar using Firefox. I followed the following tutorial
http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/

At the end of tutorial when i was opening the .XPI file it says that it is installed successfully and the browser needs to be restarted. When the browser is restarted then i can't find the toolbar anywhere. I can see it installed in the tools->addon->Extensions menu.

Anyone have any suggestions or another links to create a toolbar in firefox or internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Since your add-on appears in the add-ons list, the problem is most likley in one of the following places:

1. You may have a typo in your XUL file (make sure the markup uses the appropriate structure).
2. The paths in your chrome manifest may be invalid (again, perhaps a typo).
3. Your XPI file may not be structured properly.

Have you tried looking in the JavaScript console to see if any errors show up? [Chapter 8](http://www.borngeek.com/firefox/toolbar-tutorial/chapter-8/) of the tutorial explains a few debugging strategies in this regard, and recommends the [Console^2](http://console2.mozdev.org/) extension as a debug tool. It also recommends a few useful browser settings that may help you uncover the problem (the **javascript.options.showInConsole** setting is particularly important for catching XUL issues). Compare your code to the sample toolbar offered in the tutorial (which I just verified works properly in Firefox 9.0.1), and you'll more than likely find your mistake.

Comment: Thanks a ton dude. The path in manifest had a typo and i am able to install the toolbar. However, when i want to make any small changes in the XUL file(like adding comments to existing code), the entire toolbar is not displaying. Not able to understand where it is breaking.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct comment markup for XUL? It should be something like: `<!-- This is a comment-->`

Comment: I have given similar syntax for comments.

Comment: The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is to make sure all your elements are well formed (i.e. they are all properly closed).